# PHP: Lint/Find silent string to array conversions

Tags: php-7.2

I have to maintain old code (mainly written in PHP 5.3) and we are trying to raise it to PHP 7.2.

So far we are going well but I have a problem with silent string to array conversions.

What I mean is initializing a variable as an empty string and then use it as an array:

```php
$test = "";

$test[] = "foo";
```

This will work in older PHP version but since 7.1 will raise a fatal exception.

Is there a way, say a linter, with which i can scan the code for this kind of usage to get a list where i have to change the initialization of the variables? The application is huge so it would be a pain to do it manually...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try list files and string.

```
grep -nr '"";' .
```

IF ok, exchange

```
grep -lr '"";' . | xargs perl -p -i -e 's/"";/array();/g'
```

Comment: Well, yes, that gave me 559 lines where a variable with an empty string is defined... still a lot to check but a step in the right direction... Still many many false positives in the list. Many variables that are not used as array after string declaration

Comment: After all we used the first statement to get an overview and went through the results by hand.